# Is there a reason sklearn's TimeSeriesSplit only supports a single-step forecast horizon?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, time-series, forecasting, forecast

Sklearn's [TimeSeriesSplit](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.TimeSeriesSplit.html#sklearn.model_selection.TimeSeriesSplit) is a useful way to implement a time series equivalent of kfold cross validation.  It appears that however it only has support for a single-step horizon and no multi-step horizons e.g. it from a dataset of `[1, 2, 3, 4]` it can be used to create the following train and test sets respectively

```
[1, 2],       [3]
[1, 2, 3],    [4]
[1, 2, 3, 4], [5].
```

What is could not produce is something with a multi-step forecast horizon.  A multi-step time series split forecasting horizon would look like

```
[1, 2,],      [3, 4]
[1, 2, 3],    [4, 5]
[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6],
```

for example.

I would like to know if there is a good reason for this?  I am able to implement my own version of TimeSeriesSplit such that this isn't a problem, however I am new to the field of forecasting.  It is my understanding that using such a procedure is statistically the best way to measure the accuracy of a model.  I find it then curious that sklearn does not provide this functionality out of the box and would like to know if there is a reason why and if I have overlooked any reason as to why having a multi-step forecast horizon as shown above means my method of statistical accuracy evaluation should change?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a reason, however it is not a "good" one. Most established forecasting methods train a model on one step-ahead errors, since for multistep forecasting, they will be doing recursive forecasting instead of direct forecasting any way (i.e, for most forecasting methods, there is no use for a multi-time series split).

I suspect that's why the sklearn-authors didn't bother.

If you want to use R instead of Python, the tsCV() function performs time series splits of the type,

```
[1, 2,],      [4]
[1, 2, 3],    [5]
[1, 2, 3, 4], [6]
```

However, tsCV doesn't return the time series split itself, instead it takes a time series + forecast model as input, and returns CV based error matrix.

I don't know if it does it exactly the way you want it or not though.

Comment: What is the logic in leaving a value out in the training and test sets shown in your example?  Is there a benefit to it over leaving it in?

Comment: So for a recursive implementation is there any point in measuring the accuracy as I indicated in my question or is it redundant?

As for R or python I will try to keep to python as the rest of my project is in python as well and it will make maintenance easier, but thanks for making me aware of the R functionality if I get stuck!

Comment: @Aesir I wasn't correct in my original answer. See my edit.

Comment: @Aesir there is nothing wrong with your original idea. It's just that it hasn't been implemented in any of the standard packages. If you look at S Btaieb's paper "Machine Learning Strategies for Time Series Forecasting" he uses some formulas similar to what you are doing

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have access to the paper.  What are your thoughts on the independence and meaningful comparisons raised by @Mykhailo Lisovyi?

Comment: @Aesir here's [a link to the paper](https://s3.amazonaws.com/academia.edu.documents/41231210/Machine_Learning_Strategies_for_Time_Ser20160114-28513-1pqgoe9.pdf20160115-19908-phg1xc.pdf?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAIWOWYYGZ2Y53UL3A&Expires=1541180425&Signature=5zC%2BQ6d6RFAJVNKvZc%2BBI4uKljo%3D&response-content-disposition=inline%3B%20filename%3DMachine_Learning_Strategies_for_Time_Ser.pdf). Regarding the independence question, I posted a response to your question in cross validated that should address your concerns.

Answer (score 1):

I used the same cross-validator with more than 1 sample in a fold. But in their example [here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.TimeSeriesSplit.html#sklearn.model_selection.TimeSeriesSplit) they have just 5 samples and 5 folds, thus one sample per fold. In contrast, [here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/model_selection/plot_cv_indices.html) they already show that there are multiple samples per fold.

Your proposal is not in line with the sklearn definition of cross-validator, as folds **have to be independent**. In this sense, be careful- if you use such scheme implemented privately- your metric values in the evaluation will be correlated.

Comment: Thanks for your response.  Are you suggesting that the method I am using to evaluate a model might not be a good idea?  I used the following source to decide on it: https://otexts.org/fpp2/accuracy.html see under the heading 'Time Series Cross Validation', to me it seems to imply this is how I should evaluate the accuracy of my model.  If you have other thoughts or reasons as to why I should consider something else, I'd really like to hear about it.

Comment: Also this here: https://uk.mathworks.com/help/econ/rolling-window-estimation-of-state-space-models.html see under 'Rolling Window Analysis for Predictive Performance'.

Comment: These links seem to be reasonable, but you do an extra step in your proposal, when you make more than 1 samples in the validation folds. note that in the links their validation samples are still independent between each other (since they contain 1 sample only). This ensures that the procedure that they mention *"The forecast accuracy is computed by averaging over the test sets."* remains meaningful. Maybe, you were after an n-step-ahead validation scheme, but note that in that case there is still only a single sample in the validation sample. Such cross-validator is not available in sklearn.

Comment: What is the best way to compute the accuracy of a multi-step forecast?  I want to measure the accuracy of my model on producing a multi-step forecast.  I think that it can't be correct to say my model produces a multi-step forecast with an average accuracy of X% if I am in fact only measuring the accuracy of it performing a single-step forecast?

Comment: It depends on what do you want to achieve. Let's assume that you train on samples `[0,i]`. Then you can either evaluate on 1-step-ahead horizon `i+1`, or on n-step-ahead `i+k` or on mult-step `[i+1, i+k]`. The sklearn cross-validator provides functionality for the last option (where `k=n_total/n_cv`). 
As Alex Kinman said, most methods (like rolling window mean) can be validated with the first or second approach. But some other, like the trend fitting in [prophet](https://facebook.github.io/prophet/) allow usage of the last scheme. I can not advice on which scheme to use in your use case.

Comment: Due to your answer and comments I posted a question on stats stackexchange which might be of interest to you and explains what I do not understand in more detail: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/374954/how-to-meaningfully-compute-the-accuracy-of-a-multi-step-forecast-produced-by-a

Comment: Indeed, that's the better forum to discuss conceptual aspects of the procedure

Comment: A good example showing how to compute the accuracy of a multi-step forecast is given by Rob J Hyndman in this post: https://robjhyndman.com/hyndsight/tscvexample/ It's using R, but it is not too difficult to do the same in python.

Answer (score -1):

R tsCV() was mentioned above, for Python: check out this TSCV library:
https://pypi.org/project/tscv/

For me, it solved a similar problem with the GapWalkForward option.